# Delphi sprites (knob)

Tags: delphi, user-interface, pascal

I'm currently designing a GUI that should contain a knob.

The png file is kind of like a "motion-picture"-stacked (in lack of better words).

Let's assume the image is 32 in length,, and each knob is 32 in height: I need the code 
to go down 32 per turn. So at default the Timage is showing 32x32 of the image, but when the knob is turned up (By mouseclick and moving the mouse upwards) it shows 32x64 of the png and so on.

How would i proceed to do this ? I know I could render each image individually, and then change image one by one, but that seems like a bad way.

Comment: you may look how such a knob was implemented in floss libs, like JediVCL (ex-RxLib control)

Comment: How many frames does your picture contain ? I mean by how many degrees you want to switch to the next frame ?

Comment: The first frame should be 32x32, and when turned it goes -32 down, so the next begins at 32(keeping same lenght)x64, then 32x96 and so on. How many frames it should have all in all i don't know yet, i depends.

Comment: Even after that comment, I really don't understand your question. Could you provide an image or animation of what you want to be the result by code?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to study the GUI framework [DIB controls](http://www.delphipages.com/comp/dib_controls-4533.html) , it contains a Knob component which works exactly as you'd like to ( "Image Sprites" might be the word you were missing)

For example:

[image: DIB controls sprite loader and single frame on a few knobs]

Comment: Wow... Either Delphipages is down or no longer exists and is being sold.

Comment: https://github.com/mrpmorris/Delphi-DIBControls